# No signature of method: build_7qrj3tisvnfqjep1q5fz8onxq.android()

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\sagufta-nable\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.2.8\android\build.gradle' line: 32
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':sqflite'.

> No signature of method: build_7qrj3tisvnfqjep1q5fz8onxq.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7qrj3tisvnfqjep1q5fz8onxq$_run_closure3) values: [build_7qrj3tisvnfqjep1q5fz8onxq$_run_closure3@6c0b812b]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\SDK\flutter_windows_3.3.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 474
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

I have try to compileSdkVersion 33, but won't run.